# How to use JSDoc to tell jQuery is included?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, jsdoc

I just finished my JS code. Now I moved it into its own file, and now PHPStorm tells me that there is no variable called $. How do I fix this? (Can JSDoc solve it?)

Comment: "Settings | JavaScript | Libraries" should help. If the error comes from JSLint/JSHint, then see the answer from @dreame4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably PHPStorm sees no declaration of a `$` variable in your JS file. Check if you properly copied your code.

If `$` is a global variable (jQuery of something like that) you can add such a line at the top of your JS file `/*global $: false */`.

JSDoc has nothing to do with that as far as I know. Other tool, which is built-in PHPStorm like JSHint or JSLint, checks correctness of JavaScript code.